# Uninitialized variables using NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have built a sbc using a 80c188 processor ( 128kb ROM, 512kb RAM ). 
I have used NASM to compile the boot program with  some 'flakey' results.
My question is this:-
  since the programme is run from ROM  how can any Uninitialized variables work?  Whether or not a '.bss' section is declared within the file, the variables don't work as expected. ( this will probably seem obvious to most!)
 I assume they must be pointed to an area in RAM in order to work.
But I do't understand the mechanism to do this.
Bear in mind, there is no OS on board, this what I am trying to create.
Any help would stop me going nuts.

Comment: Why do you think it's uninitialized variables that are the problem?

Comment: Are you assuming the BSS is zero-initialized, like it is in a program on a normal OS?  Does a BIOS load your code, or is your code literally the first thing that runs?  What memory space does the BSS refer to?  How do you make sure that BSS memory doesn't overlap with data or code memory?

Comment: I don't use BSS in my programme, I tried it, but it made no difference.

Comment: I don't use BSS in my programme, I tried it, but it made no difference. My code is the first thing that runs and simply configures the cpu and peripherals. The code loops a routine that initializes a 85c30 SCC, I tried using variables to do this, but the results were unpredictable. As I am new to this kind of project, and evidently really really rubbish at coding, the programme was pulled together from snippets all over the internet ( thanks everybody!). It seems most of my code is a bit flakey, not just the variables.I hope this makes it a little clearer, thanks.